# String initialization in multidimensional array

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

How to assign string value in multidimensional array, send the array as a function argument, and return it back to main function? I tried this but it gives an error:

```
char a[250][250][250];   // does not work
a[][0][2] = "0";         // does not work
a[][1][2] = "0";         // does not work

char a[][2][2] = {"0", "1"};  // works

// error: expected primary-expression before ']' token
a[i][j][max] = add_func(a[i][j][], i, j);
```

Comment: You're confusing characters and strings. Your array is array of `char`s, not strings.

Comment: 15.6MB of string data. poor, poor stack.

Comment: `char *a[250][250]` will save **96%** space.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After declaration you can not assign, but use `strcpy()`

```
char a[250][250][250];

strcpy(a[0][1],"0");
```

or assign at the time of declaration:

```
char a[250][250][250] = {"0","2"};  
char a[][250][250] = {"0","2"};
```

or if you want to assign a single char.

```
a[i][j][k] = '0';
```

Where i, j, k are any value less than 250

---

### How to Declaration and Initialization 3D Array IN C

In-general `a[3][4][2]` is a three-dimension array, that can be view as

`a[3][4][2]` : Consist of **3 two-dimension arrays**, where **each 2-D array are consist of 4-rows and 2-colunms**. can be declare as:

```
char a[3][4][2] =  { 
                       { //oth 2-D array 
                         {"0"},
                         {"1"},
                         {"2"},
                         {"4"}
                       },
                       { //1th 2-D Array
                         {"0"},
                         {"1"},
                         {"2"},
                         {"4"}
                       },
                       { //2nd 2-D array
                         {"0"},
                         {"1"},
                         {"2"},
                         {"4"}
                       },
                   };
```

**Note**: "1" means two chars, one additional fro null ('\0') char.

**If integer array:**

```
int a[3][2][3]=  
        {
            { //oth 2-D array, consists of 2-rows and 3-cols
            {11, 12, 13},
            {17, 18, 19}
            },
            {//1th 2-D array, consists of 2-rows and 3-cols
            {21, 22, 23},
            {27, 28, 29}
            },
            {//2th 2-D array, consists of 2-rows and 3-cols
            {31, 32, 33},
            {37, 38, 39}
            },
        };
```

[**Link to understand**](http://rajkishor09.hubpages.com/hub/How-to-work-with-Multidimensional-Array-in-C-Programming)

---

**Second error**:

to this `a[i][j][max]` a char can assign not string so,

```
a[i][j][max] = '0' ; // is correct  expression
```

but

```
a[i][j][max] = "0";  // is not correct, wrong
```

---

Please  read [**WhozCraig comment**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14089514/string-initialization-in-multidimensional-array#comment19486006_14089514). you are declaring huge memory in stack!

---

According to [**your comment**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14089514/string-initialization-in-multidimensional-array/14089530#comment19486134_14089530) :

function declaration:

```
char add_func(char a[250][250][250], int i, int j); // function definition
```

try like this:

```
  char a[250][250][250];
  a[i][j][max] = add_func(a, i, j );
```

Comment: @sabbir_pstu : Which passing to a function ?

Comment: the present value of a[][][] will be passed to function as function parameter and return other multidimensional array variable.

Comment: @sabbir_pstu  ok I guess it should be like `add_func( a, i, j );` can't assign to `a[i][j][max]`

Comment: @sabbir_pstu: you need to show definition of `add_func`, then I can help you.

Comment: char add_func(char a[250][250][250], int i, int j);    // function defination

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im : Hi Shiplu! Please check again, if still an error let me know..thanks!

Comment: @sabbir_pstu improved my answer, your can recheck

Answer (score 7):

To **initialize** character strings table you can use curly braces. And the outer most dimension (I dont know how else can it be called) or the left most number in square is optional.

So this will work

```
char table[][3][10] = {
    {"row1-col1", "row1-col2", "row1-col3"},
    {"row2-col1", "row2-col2", "row2-col3"},
    {"row3-col1", "row3-col2", "row3-col3"},
    {"row4-col1", "row4-col2", "row4-col3"}
    };
```

You dont need to type `table[4][3][10]`. Compiler calculates it.  The size of `table` is 120 bytes. As the contents are all string you can use

```
char *table[][3] = ...
```

This will **save  20% space**.

Curly braces can only be used in initializing phase. Not after that. hence following code will not work.

```
a[][0][2] = "0";
```

Comment: +1, and a mentor long ago called it the "superior" dimension of the array. All others he referred to as "inferior" dimensions. I've also seen them called "dominant" and "sub-dominant".

Answer (score 2):

You probably would like to use pointers instead:

```
char *a[2][2] = { "0", "1", "2", "3" };
```

Comment: Assuming each entry isn't going to be altered, that will work.

Comment: Definitely true. But you still can assign individual strings by constructs like `a[i][j] = "something"` or `a[i][j] = strdup(something)`.