# 3D Array of _unequal numbers_ of strings

Tags: c, arrays, string

I realise this has probably been done before but searching has turned up blank for this specific wrinkle.

If we want to define an array containing some strings, we can do:

```
char *strings[] = {"one","two","three"};
```

And if we want to define an array of arrays of strings, we can do:

```
char *strings[][] =
{
  {"one","two","three"},
  {"first","second","third"},
  {"ten","twenty","thirty"}
};
```

But I can't seem to do this:

```
char *strings[][] =
{
  {"one","two"},
  {"first","second","third","fourth","fifth"},
  {"ten","twenty","thirty"}
};
```

Doing that throws compiler errors.

(Examples from [string initialization in multidimensional array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14089514/string-initialization-in-multidimensional-array))

Comment: What compiler errors?

Comment: error: array type has incomplete element type
and
warning: braces around scalar initializer

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083658/jagged-array-in-c

Comment: Thanks SuvP - declaring the bounds was my next experiment!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12813494/why-do-we-need-to-specify-the-column-size-when-passing-a-2d-array-as-a-parameter),

```
char *strings[][]
```

`strings` is a 2D array.

Incase of,

```
char *strings[][] =
{
  {"one","two","three"},
  {"first","second","third"},
  {"ten","twenty","thirty"}
};
```

The compiler automatically determines the no of columns in `strings`. In this case **each** `strings[i]` is  a row in the 2D array. Also, its a pointer (array names are pointers) of type `char (*string)[3]` i.e. to char array of sixe 3.

```
char *strings[][] =
{
  {"one","two"},
  {"first","second","third","fourth","fifth"},
  {"ten","twenty","thirty"}
};
```

In this case, the compiler can't create an array (the array has to have elements of same type) because `strings[0]` would be of type `char (*strings)[2]`, `strings[1]` would be of type `char (*strings)[5]` and `strings[2]` would be of type `char (*strings)[3]`

Hence, the compiler says `incomplete element type`.

You need to specify the number of columns (N) at declaration(which will make each row of type `char (*string)[N]`)  or assign dynamically.