# Cant write a 2d array on a FILE on C

Tags: arrays, c, file

```
char arrTypeLabels[3][7]= {{"Random"},{"ASC"},{"DESC"}};
FILE *f;
    f= fopen( "TIMES.txt", "wb");
    if (f == NULL)
    {
    printf("Error! Could not open file\n");
    exit(-1);
    }
    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
    for(j=0;j<7;j++)
    {
    printf("%c",arrTypeLabels[i][j]);
    fwrite(arrTypeLabels[i][j],sizeof(char),sizeof(arrTypeLabels),f);   
    }
    }
    fclose(f);aenter code here
```

> Im opening the TIMES.txt file but i cant see any output, althought i think my code is right .......................... :/ pls help...

Comment: Check with this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14089514/string-initialization-in-multidimensional-array)

Comment: The error from the compiler tells you the fwrite call is wrong.  You are passing a char where a pointer is required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
char arrTypeLabels[3][7] = {
    {"Random"},
    {"ASC"},
    {"DESC"}
};
FILE *f = fopen("TIMES.txt", "wb"); //wb is OK
if (f == NULL)
{
    printf("Error! Could not open file\n");
    exit(-1);
}
int i, j;
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < 7; j++)
    {
        printf("%c", arrTypeLabels[i][j]);
        fwrite(arrTypeLabels[i] + j, sizeof (char), sizeof (char), f);  //your mistake is here
    }
}
fclose(f);
```

I don't know how you're even able to copile your code, because in `fwrite`, the first argument needs to be a pointer, or in your code, you're giving the value.
Also, what you're trying to do is confusing, because it looks like you're trying to write `char` by `char`, but you're attempting to write the whole data contained in `arrTypeLabels` in one `fwrite` call.

Answer (score 0):

`fwrite` first and third parameters are wrong. Since you want to write char by char, your line should be `fwrite(&buf[i][j], 1,1,f);`

Or simplier, use `fputc`:

```
 fputc(buf[i][j], f);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to write that array to a file, you can make something like :

```
char arrTypeLabels[3][7]= {{"Random"},{"ASC"},{"DESC"}};
    FILE *f;
    f= fopen( "TIMES.txt", "wb");
    if (f == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error! Could not open file\n");
        exit(-1);
    }
    fwrite(arrTypeLabels,sizeof(char),sizeof(arrTypeLabels),f);
    fclose(f);
```

or something like :

```
char arrTypeLabels[3][7]= {{"Random"},{"ASC"},{"DESC"}};
    FILE *f;
    f= fopen( "TIMES.txt", "wb");
    if (f == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error! Could not open file\n");
        exit(-1);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++)
            fwrite(arrTypeLabels[i] + j,sizeof(char),sizeof(char),f);
    }
    fclose(f);
```

note that the first method is much faster since you don't have to write (to a file i.e into the hard drive) every single character one at a time.